# how to get what are the images are on the screen at runtime in android sdk

Tags: android

I don't know how to get the images what are available on the scree. I'm using imageview for the purpose of display the images on the screen. 
**Images will be changed randomly** because i stored the images into array and images are in drawable. **I want to know which image is displays on the screen at runtime**.

thank u

Comment: Do you want to know the name of image which was loaded?

Comment: yes, also the loaded image id

Answer (score 0):

When you change the image in the `ImageView`, hold onto the array index that you used in another variable.

Comment: In additional to answer you can use `Map<Bitmap, String> images` for example.